# Select first working day from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as shown below. in the day's array, it has various days which has both working and non-working days. now I want to consider first type=" working" as the start_date.
could you help me. thanks

```
Array
(
[error] => 0
[data] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 2018-03-11
        [end_date] => 2018-03-21
        [days] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => non_working
                        [sub_type] => weekend
                        [sub_sub_type] => 
                        [date] => 2018-03-11
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => working
                        [sub_type] => 
                        [sub_sub_type] => 
                        [full_date] => 2018-03-12
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => working
                        [sub_type] => 
                        [sub_sub_type] => 
                        [full_date] => 2018-03-13
                    )
           )
      )
)
```

I've tries this as of now:

```
$i=0;
$var = array();
foreach($arr['data']['days'][$i] as $var) {
    if($var['type'] == 'working') {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, can you post code here?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan added that in the question

Comment: what would be your expected result from above array?

Answer (score 1):

Rework `$arr['data']['days'][$i]` to `$arr['data']['days']`:

```
$start = null;
foreach($arr['data']['days'] as $var) {
    if($var['type'] == 'working') {
        $start = $var['date'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check now - `$start` variable should contains the starting date.

Comment: If this if statement is in a fucntion, use `return` instead of  `break`